# How to restore IIS settings and Default Web Site?

Tags: iis, iis-8

On Windows 8.1 with IIS8. 
How to restore IIS settings and Default Web Site?

I've a machine that all the application pools and web sites have been deleted from its IIS.
I've tried to remove and reinstall the IIS, but even after reinstall the `Default Web Site` and `DefaultAppPool` are not restored.

I would like to restore the IIS to the same point like when it is first installed.

Comment: Restore from a backup?  Remove and reinstall IIS?  What 'settings' are you looking to restore?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @techie007: I've added more info to the question

Comment: I don't have IIS8 handy to test with, but here's a couple things to check/try: http://girdharbisht.com/girdhar/?cat=47, and http://mscodingblog.blogspot.ca/2012/11/create-default-iis-website-using.html maybe someone will come along with a specific answer., or if you figure it out, please post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In short: Reinstall both IIS and WAS.

In details -

**Step 1**

1. Go to "Add remove programs"
2. "Turn windows features on or off"
3. Remove both IIS and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)
4. Restart the PC

**Step 2**

1. Go to "Add remove programs"
2. "Turn windows features on or off"
3. Turn on both IIS and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)

**Note:** Reinstalling IIS alone won't help. You have to reinstall both IIS and WAS

Comment: Worked great! I found that removing IIS did not fully delete the contents of the inetpub folder which might have been due to permission issues.  I deleted that as well in addition to your steps.

Comment: A similar process is posted as the accepted answer in this [IIS.NET forum thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1154336.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

**You don't need to reinstall the whole IIS or WAS!**

If it's just about creating the *Default Web Site*, reinstalling the whole IIS and WAS is little bit too much "aggressive" solution and absolutely the last thing to do if everything else fails. I was able to recreate it manually using **IIS Manager**.

Check [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis/30083183#30083183) where it's explained in detail.

I have deleted *Default Web Site* accidentally at some point of time most probably. When I was trying to open a project configured to run under IIS in Visual Studio, it failed to load with an error message:

"*The Web Application Project is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://localhost:8080/' could not be found.*"

After I have recreated *Default Web Site* in IIS Manager as [described in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis/30083183#30083183), I was able to reload and open that specific project.

This was the complete process to restore the *Default Web Site* in my case (**IIS 7** on Windows 7 64bit):

1. open **IIS Manager**
2. right click *Sites* node under your machine in the *Connections* tree on the left side and click **Add Website**
3. enter "**Default Web Site**" as a *Site name*
4. set *Application pool* back to **DefaultAppPool**!
5. set *Physical path* to `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`
6. leave *Binding* and everything else as is

Check [my answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750632/recreate-the-default-website-in-iis/30083183#30083183) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting errors starting up IIS and you running a shared iis configuration. Make sure that your redirection.config in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config has the correct username and password for the network share....

Saved me a complete IIS reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Also, unless you specify it, the new web site that receives a connection only is open to incoming connect port 80. Not 8080. You can set the port. Also, you can list what protocols to receive for your connection separated by commas.